# Disabling only Reverse Portrait in Xamarin Forms

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

How can I disable reverse portrait for Xamarin forms app? (preferably all devices but specifically in android)

Answer (score 1):

You should do that locally for each native project.

**iOS:** Open Info.Plist and select **Supported Device Orientations**

**Android:** Open MainActivity.cs class, and change annotation of MainActivity as

```
[Activity(ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Landscape|ScreenOrientation.Portrait, Label = "your app name", ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
```

**Windows Phone**(Assuming retargeted 8.1) Open Package.appxmanifest and change orientations from Supported rotations.